# Grails Atmosphere Broadcaster not working

Tags: grails, atmosphere

I am trying to implement atmosphere plugin in my grails application. I have the following code

```
class AtmosphereService {

static transactional = true

static atmosphere = [mapping: '/atmosphere/status']

static exposes = ['jms']

@Subscriber(topic='msgevent')
def onEvent(msg) {

    def payload = msg
    if(msg instanceof Map) {
        // convert map messages to JSON
        payload = msg.encodeAsJSON()
    }

    // broadcast to the atmosphere
    broadcaster['/atmosphere/status'].broadcast(payload)
    println("jms service->  "+payload)
    /*Broadcaster brod = lookupBroadcaster(msg["id"], false)
    brod.broadcast(payload)*/

    return null
}
```

I also added the onRequest and onStateChange closures. But i am getting a "nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: broadcaster for class: com.AtmosphereService" exception. I cannot understand what I did wrong. Can someone please help me with this . Thanks